# Query sql to get the first occurrence in a many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have a User table that has a many to many relationship with Areas. This relationship is stored in the Rel_User_area table. I want to show the user name and the first area that appears in the list of areas.
Ex.

**User**

```
id | Name    
1  | Peter    
2  | Joe
```

**Area**

```
id | Name    
1  | Area A    
2  | Area B
3  | Area C
```

**Rel_User_area**

```
iduser | idarea    
1      | 1    
1      | 3    
2      | 3
```

The result I want:

```
User Name | Area    
Peter     |Area A    
Joe       |Area C
```

Comment: Is that "First" when sorted by area `id`? Like you want the `min(area.id)` for each user and it's respective name.

Comment: Not necessarily, it must be the first one that appears in the relationship table.

Comment: That's the problem.  As records are inserted/deleted first changes.  Do you have a "TimeStamp" column/field on the table which could tell us first?  Keep in mind data in tables is UNORDERED.  you have to provide an order or a way of ordering.

Comment: In the relationship table I have an id, so I could select the minimum.

Comment: Ok... and now what RDBMS (mySQL, Postgreql, SQL Server, oracle, DB2...Sybase, msAccess, FoxPro, Act, Firebird...)  not all SQL is the same.  Each has different functions/features.  Some support analytical functions or cross apply which can make this easy.  mySQL doesn't so we'd have to take a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the minimum area id to determine "First" you could use a correlated subquery (A subquery that refers to field(s) in the main query to filter results):

```
SELECT user.name, area.name
FROM 
    user 
    INNER JOIN Rel_User_Area RUA ON user.id = RUA.iduser
    INNER JOIN Area ON RUA.idarea = area.id
WHERE area.id = (SELECT min(idarea) FROM Rel_User_Area WHERE iduser = RUA.iduser)
```

There's other ways of doing this that may be RDBMS specific. Like in Teradata I would use a QUALIFY clause that doesn't exist in MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.. Regardless of the RDBMS the above should work.

```
SELECT user.name, area.name
FROM 
    user 
    INNER JOIN Rel_User_Area RUA ON user.id = RUA.iduser
    INNER JOIN Area ON RUA.idarea = area.id
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user.id ORDER BY area.id ASC) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

using the ID from Rel_user_Area you mentioned in comments...

This should be pretty platform independent.

```
SELECT U.name as Username, A.Name as Area
FROM (SELECT min(ID) minID, IDUser, IDarea
      FROM Rel_user_Area
      GROUP BY IDUser, IDarea) UA
INNER JOIN User U
 on U.ID = UA.IDuser
INNER JOIN Area A
 on A.ID = UA.IDArea
```

If Cross apply and top work (could substitute limit 1 vs top if Postgresql or mySQL)

This will run the cross apply SQL once for each record in user; thus you get the most recent rel_user_Area ID per user.

```
SELECT U.name as Username, A.Name as Area
FROM User U
 on U.ID = UA.IDuser
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 IDUser, IDArea 
             FROM Rel_user_Area z
             WHERE Z.IDUSER = U.ID
             ORDER BY ID ASC) UA
INNER JOIN Area A
 on A.ID = UA.IDArea
```